# Eclipse connects to web even though I have not specified necessary proxy

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy

This is sort of a puzzling situation.  I have a portable version of Eclipse running on a machine which needs to use a proxy to access the web.  I have not input any of this proxy information into Eclipse settings, as far as I can remember.  In fact, below you can see what the network preferences look like (I'm not sure what the "Dynamic" entries mean).

I've grep'd the entire installation folder for the name of my proxy server, and it does not seem to be in there anywhere.  I don't think there are configuration files for this portable installation anywhere else.

However, even though I have no proxy specified, Eclipse is able to get through to the internet fine (tested with internal browser, marketplace, SVN/GIT repos, etc).  How is this possible?  I am unfortunately unable to install Wireshark on this machine, but I am fairly certain Eclipse is sending its requests to the proxy somehow.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice where it says "Native"

If this is on a Windows machine (as evidenced by the look of the window) this means that it is using the proxy settings that you set in IE.

(You set that proxy info in IE9, for example, from the "internet options" choice under the 'gear icon' and choose 'connections' and click the "Lan Settings" button.)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I figured it had to be borrowing the info from somewhere in the system. :-)